# Create a list of choices for selectInput using 2 lists

Tags: r, vector, shiny

I have a `selectInput` menu that I created manually:

```
  selectInput(inputId = "group_by",
              label = "Grouping Options:",
              choices = c("Product" = "PRODUCT_NAME", 
                          "Capacity" = "PRODUCT_CAPACITY", 
                          "Month" = "CALENDAR_MONTH", 
                          "Line of Business" = "LOB")
  )
```

I want to simplify this so I do not have to edit it every time a change happens to the choices.

I have 2 lists already and for the application I want to be able to only edit those lists and have the rest of the app generate what is needed based on the lists.

The two lists are:

```
column_names <- c('PRODUCT_NAME', 'PRODUCT_CAPACITY', 
             'CALENDAR_MONTH', 'LOB')
aliases <- c('Product', 'Capacity', 'Date', 'Line of Business')
```

I want to change this chunk of code into a more adaptive chunk that utilizes the vector `aliases` and the vector `column_names` to create the choice list instead of:

```
c("Product" = "PRODUCT_NAME", 
  "Capacity" = "PRODUCT_CAPACITY", 
  "Month" = "CALENDAR_MONTH", 
  "Line of Business" = "LOB")
```

I think I could use lapply or sapply but I am not very strong with those and I do need it to have the `aliases = column_name` so the menu displays the "nice" names (`aliases`) but also knows where to find it in the data (`column_names`)

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide name to `column_names` vector using `aliases` as:

```
names(column_names) <- aliases

column_names
#        Product           Capacity               Date   Line of Business 
# "PRODUCT_NAME" "PRODUCT_CAPACITY"   "CALENDAR_MONTH"              "LOB"
```

The above value is similar to key-value representation. You can verify it as:

```
v <- c("Product" = "PRODUCT_NAME", 
  "Capacity" = "PRODUCT_CAPACITY", 
  "Date" = "CALENDAR_MONTH", 
  "Line of Business" = "LOB")

v
#        Product           Capacity              Date   Line of Business 
# "PRODUCT_NAME" "PRODUCT_CAPACITY"   "CALENDAR_MONTH"              "LOB" 


identical(column_names,v)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order is always the same, what you can do is, just putting your aliases in the selectInput

```
selectInput(inputId = "group_by",
             label = "Grouping Options:",
             choices = aliases)
```

And then, every time you need your column name, you just take the index that corresponds to your choice

```
column_names[which(aliases == input$group_by)]
```

Comment: This could be a good workaround if there is not a way to directly assign them in  `selectInput`